# Disable RequiredFieldValidator when ControlToValidate is not visible in client

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a series of ASP.Net RequiredFieldValidators that, together with their associated controls, get hidden client side - They are encased in a div, and I use jQuery's .toggle() to hide/show the div as required:

```
<div id="reference" style="display: none">
<asp:TextBox runat="Server" id="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="Server" id="rfv" ControlToValidate="txt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

(simplified)

Toggling the **div** off adds a style of "*display: none*", as expected. The RequiredFieldValidator will still fire as, although hidden, it's still a active within the page. I need to disable validators that are not visible in the client.

Using jQuery, how can I can find all controls to be validated/validators that have a parent **div** with "display: none", and disable them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical. I post my question, and then manage to work it out myself minutes later. This is what I ended up with:

```
function ConfigureValidators() {
    if (typeof Page_Validators != 'undefined') {
        for (i = 0; i <= Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i] != null) {
                var visible = $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).parent().is(':visible');
                Page_Validators[i].enabled = visible;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Although my code does appear to cause the validators to fire/validate immediately!?

Comment: Hmmm... ValidatorEnable() appears to call ValidatorValidate().

Comment: Updated my code block, using the .enabled in place of the call to ValidatorEnabled(). It now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
ValidatorEnable(ValidatorName, false);
```

[ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) - look under the **Client Side API** sub-heading.

In your case:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    ValidatorEnable('<%=rfv.ClientID %>', false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you use backend validation then check this out, it worked for me.

```
Requiredfieldvalidator.Enabled = False
```

The project I am working has all the fields visible but based on certain conditions, validation has to be disabled.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63039498/1920574)