# disable RequiredFieldvalidator

Tags: jquery, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have **RequiredFieldvalidator** and I want in certain cases to **disable** it.

this is the RequiredFieldvalidator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvHul" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error" ControlToValidate="txtBox" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and I've tried to do this but all these lines of code gave me **Page_IsValid = false**

```
 $("#RfvHul").attr("disabled", true);

 ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%=RfvHul.ClientID%>"), false);

 document.getElementById("RfvHul").Enabled = false;

 $("#RfvHul").attr("Enabled", false);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please go through with this link: http://techbrij.com/dynamically-enable-disable-validator-isvalid-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just disable it client side and expect the server side code to know about it.  You'll have to repeat your disabling logic server side prior to calling Validate().

Answer (score 0):

I found the below code working for me.

```
Requiredfieldvalidator.Enabled = False
```

The project I am working has all the fields visible but based on certain conditions,  validation has to be disabled.

The backend language I am using is VB but frontend side it's the same.